# Executing UI Code from ViewModel on MVVMCross

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, mvvmcross

I have just started using MvvmCross, but i didn't find any info about to how i can execute UI code from a ViewModel.

On Caliburn there are coroutine so i can access the view and keep the ui code separated from the viewmodel code.
on my first case i need to open a dialow from a command inside a ViewModel, what is the correct way?

Right now i'm developing a WinRT app.

Thanks

Comment: As well as providing an answer on what you can do today, I've also added https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/issues/197 - if you've got any requests please do add them in - always happy to consider if there's anything we can add across all platforms :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There isn't any hard/fast rule on this within MvvmCross.

Generally, when I need to do this I use the Messenger plugin.

This answer assumes you are using the latest Alpha `v3` code. For older vNext code you'll have to do some translation - see notes below.

To use this approach:

I reference `Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Messenger.dll` from both Core and UI projects.

Then I add a line somewhere in Setup.cs (e.g. in `InitializeLastChance`) to:

```
Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Messenger.PluginLoader.Instance.EnsureLoaded();
```

Then in the Core project I add a message:

```
public class InputIsNeededMessage : MvxMessage
{
    public InputIsNeededMessage(object sender) : base(sender) {}
}
```

In the ViewModel I can get the Messenger by constructor injection or by:

```
var messenger = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxMessenger>();
```

and I can send messages by calling:

```
messenger.Publish(new InputIsNeededMessage(this));
```

In the View I can again get to the messenger and subscribe to messages using:

```
var messenger = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxMessenger>();
_token = messenger.SubscribeOnMainThread<InputIsNeededMessage>(OnInputIsNeeded);
```

where `_token` **must** be a member variable - if it isn't then the subscription won't persist - the subscription itself is **weak** by default (so you never have to unsubscribe)

and where `OnInputIsNeeded` is something like:

```
private void OnInputIsNeeded(InputIsNeededMessage message)
{
    if (message.Sender != ViewModel)
        return;

    // do stuff here - you are already on the UI thread
}
```

---

The above sequence is what I normally do for 'proper code'

To start with using a Messenger/EventAggregator can feel uncomfortable - it certainly took me a while to get used to it - but after I did get used to it, then I now use it everywhere - the pub/sub Message decoupling is very flexible for testing and for future maintenance of code (IMO)

As alternatives to this approach above I do sometimes take shortcuts:

- sometimes I fire normal C# events from the ViewModel and have the View respond to these
- sometimes I have special marker properties and fire the UI code from them

---

Sorry for using `v3` syntax - but the changeover is coming and it's what I'm now coding in...

To switch back to `vNext` I think you might need to:

- use `IMessenger` instead of `IMvxMessenger`
- use `BaseMessage` instead of the `MvxMessage`
- use `Subscribe` instead of `SubscribeOnMainThread` - but then you will need to marshall the message onto the UI thread yourself.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the detailed explanation, i will check that branch tomorrow. I was already used to use EventAggregator on Caliburn for other purposes, so i think i will at home :) sorry i didn't notice that plugin. Thanks for your help

Comment: hi i am also using the same messaging pattern in iOS application, but the problem is the messages are displayed many times. this happens when you move back and forth in view. ex. i have a login view and feedback view which comes after login. so once i login and move to feedback view,and fill up field of that page, it's working fine. but if i now navigate back to login and again come back to feedback view and filled up fields and when tap on "Done" button i get many messages. can you guide me what will be the resolution of this situation?

Comment: Can i use it for message passing from view to viewmodel ?

Comment: @Stuart - I have a MvxListView with multiselection mode. I want to toggle its clicked item color. If it is a listview then I can do it by code on view. But how can I do same task in MVVMCross ? Because MvxListView Itemclick is  bind on View Model and here we not get clicked item object not get. Please help

Answer (score 0):

There exists an easier way. Here is the method I use for executing any action on the main 
thread:

```
protected void RunOnUIThread(Action action) {
    var dispatcher = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxMainThreadDispatcher>();
    dispatcher.RequestMainThreadAction(action);
}
```

Hope it helps. Cheers.