# How to send Broadcast from MVVMCross ViewModel

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross

I want to fire a broadcast event from ViewModel for particular error scenario. How can I access intent and SendBroadcast in ViewModel?

Comment: Have you looked into MvvmCross' Messenger plugin?

Comment: @Nikola Yes i did, but coudnt found any reference.

Comment: it is on n=9 -> http://slodge.blogspot.dk/2013/05/n9-getting-message-n1-days-of-mvvmcross.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @nikola suggested, by using Messanger pluging, one can make native calls from ViewModel.

More information : [Executing UI Code from ViewModel on MVVMCross](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15590776/executing-ui-code-from-viewmodel-on-mvvmcross)