# c# - Passing data between two fragments

Tags: c#, android, android-fragments, xamarin.android

I am trying to get data from fragmentA into my other fragment i.e fragmentB. In my fragmentA there is a Edittext field and when user hit submit button, the data from Edittext should display in my fragmentB. I tried to follow [this link](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/8453/passing-data-from-one-fragment-to-another) but since I am new to xamarin mobile dev area I couldn't figure out the answer. Can anyone help me with this issue.

I tried doing this but I am not getting any data from fragmentA to fragmentB
**fragmentA**

```
submitButton.Click += delegate
        {
            TrackInfoFragment fragment = new TrackInfoFragment();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.PutString("message", "From Activity");
            fragment.Arguments = bundle;
        };
```

**fragmentB**

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        string test = bundle.GetString("message");
        Console.WriteLine("Test: " + test);
```

Comment: If you use Xamarin Forms, then the easy way to pass data between two components is to use [MessagingCenter](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/messaging-center/). However, I suspect you use Xamarin Android. In that case you can take a look at [MvvmCross](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross). It's a cross platform library that encourages Mvvm pattern and allows you to move even more application code into a cross platform library. As a bonus it also contains a messaging (Publisher/Subscriber) component.

Comment: @AnatoliyPidlubnyy in my separate tutorial project, I tried using MvvmCross framework but it had the same issue and also there are not many tutorials out there for api integration, communicating between components, etc. and all this things I need into my application. That's why I am not using this framework. If you have any good tutorial for this framework then please let me know. I can give a go again. Thanks

Comment: I feel your pain. I took me a bit of googling to convert my Xamarin.Androind app MvvmCross. The documentation is a bit lacking but the framework is worth of time spending to learn it. Here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15592431/6105337) to help you figure out how to use the MvvmCross Messenger.

Comment: And the link to the [Messenger plugin documentation](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/plugins/messenger?scroll=1238)

Answer (score 0):

You are instantiating a new bundle.
On fragmentB, get data from `Arguments`.

Instead of:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
string test = bundle.GetString("message");
Console.WriteLine("Test: " + test);
```

Try

```
string test = Arguments.GetString("message");
Console.WriteLine("Test: " + test);
```

Hope it helps...

Sources: [Xamarin Android passing variable from Activity to Fragment returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26509072/xamarin-android-passing-variable-from-activity-to-fragment-returns-null)

Comment: I'm sorry, but can you try this (from https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/70756/#Comment_70756) on the calling Activity:
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.PutString("message", "From Activity");
    TrackInfoFragment fragment = new TrackInfoFragment() { Arguments = bundle }
As the answer says, arguments needs to get persisted...